# Rails select NoMethodError in Messages#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to put on a select box the Users who will receive the message.
What we have is one table named Messages, one named Users and one named Friendships, on message table we have user_id (sender) and friend_id (receiver) both foreign key to Users ID.

And this is the error returning: undefined method `friend_id' for #Message:0x56f6238

That been said, I'm trying to vinculate all Friendships entries with current_user id and then using friend_id to search on Users table all users that current_user is able to send message.

Any help with this error? I'm really new on Ruby On Rails development.
If I'm missing some info, let me know.
Thanks in advance

On our application, the new_message_path renders one partial which contains the following:

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
  <% if @message.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this message from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Receiver" %><br />
    <%= f.select :friend_id, Message.all.collect {|friendships| [ friendships.friend_id ] }, { include_blank: true } %>
  </div><br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And on our model named Message we have this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :friend_id
  validates_presence_of :content, :friend_id, presence => true

  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?

Comment: @user2737446, by the looks of attr_accessible it looks like you're using rails 3, otherwise your would be using strong_parameters. Either way the error is saying that you haven't defined friend_ id.. Have you defined frined_id ?

Comment: @RichPeck, no, i'm using rails 3.

Comment: @RussellKompinski, hm, actually I don't think I have defined it anywhere. On our application we have a similiar funcionality and I'm doing it based on that. So, sorry for asking, but where should i Define it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks - just checking!

Comment: For site wide availability it needs to be a helper method defined in app/controllers/application_controller.rb. So friend_id does exist in the application and db and has an association with user_id, yes? And to clarify you're trying to send 1 message to the many users that have the parameters of friend_id?

Comment: @user2737446, For site wide availability it needs to be a helper method defined in app/controllers/application_controller.rb. So friend_id does exist in the application and db and has an association with user_id, yes? And to clarify you're trying to send 1 message to the many users that have the parameters of friend_id?

Comment: @RussellKompinski I'm trying to send 1 message to one user that have the parameters of friend id. So, the ideia is to look on friendship table to see which user_id is related to current_user. And then send the message to the chosen friend.

So, I'll have to define friend_id on application_controller?
I guess there's no need to be site wide avaible, only for this functionality.

Comment: Make sure your messages table actually has a column called friend_id.

Comment: @davidfurber yes it has friend_id and user_id for current_user

Comment: What is you try a collection_select instead? That's what it is for.

Comment: @davidfurber, fetching some examples on internet and here on stackoverflow for collection_select i've made this:
But I don't really know collection_select and how to implement that inside form_for or how to link the three involved tables.

    <select name="message[user_id]">
      <% Friendship.all.each do |message| %>
        <option value="<%= User.id %>"><%= User.name_with_initial %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>

Comment: You're building a list of users to show in a dropdown. Build it in the controller and pass it to the collection_select.